# Insert a 'NULL' string in a table in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, null

I would like to know if it is possible to insert a 'null' string in a column which has a `NOT NULL` constraint.

I'm using PostgreSQL, although this probably applies to other database management systems as well.

The query would look like the below

```
INSERT INTO originators(originator, id, regexp)
VALUES ('null', 1, -1);
```

This is the table design:

```
CREATE TABLE originators
(
      originator    varchar(30)    NOT NULL
    , id            int            NOT NULL
    , regexp        int            NOT NULL
);
```

Here the originator column has a `NOT NULL` constraint, so there should be no NULL values in the table.

However, when I query the table, I'm seeing this:

```
╔════════════╦════╦════════╗
║ originator ║ id ║ regexp ║
╠════════════╬════╬════════╣
║ NULL       ║  1 ║     -1 ║
╚════════════╩════╩════════╝
```

How is this possible?

Answer (score 6):

`'NULL'` is not the same as `NULL`, the first one is an string just like any other string, so your constraint (`NOT NULL`) won't work.

I think you are working with a programming language (like PHP or Java) that you put your value inside a string with a variable like

```
INSERT INTO originators(originator, id, regexp) 
VALUES ('$variable', $id, $regexp);
```

so in this case you have to correct your code to prevent the quotes, or if you can't do that you constraint should be `CHECK(upper(originator) != 'NULL')`.